# MTG -- Search for a sorcery -- Green -- EDH

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

I am building an EDH/Commander deck and my commander is mono green...

I want a card or a combo that allows me to search my library for a sorcery card (or something similar).

Do you guys know something about this? I searched on scryfall and didn't found anything relevant

Comment: Another way, instead of tutoring, would be drawing a lot of cards. Beast Whisperer with Ancestral Statue and infinite mana. But you would have all your lands in your hand, or at least a lot. Mangara's Tome is something random in colorless such as phyrexian portal. Planar Portal is probably what you are looking for, but you can't tutor it with the common green tutors, so it's the same as with your sorcery.

Comment: The card I’m searching for is a finisher for my deck... My commander makes me elemental with power and thoughness equal to the number of lands I control... that sorcery allows me to double my lands.

Comment: Maybe go with a self mill strategy? Green has a decent number of cards that can retrieve a Sorcery from the Graveyard like Regrowth and Eternal Witness, and it has plenty of cards that could get lands back out of the Graveyard which would help your commander as well.  For example, World Shaper is a Creature, can help with self milling, and it could easily double the number of Lands you have out in that kind of strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interacting with sorceries is very much outside of the Green part of the color pie, so this kind of effect is going to be rare at best.

As a basic first search, the following Scryfall search finds every card compatible with a Green commander that has you search your library: [`o:"search your library" ci:g`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22search%20your%20library%22%20ci%3Ag). The `o:` search term specifies text in the card's text box to look for, and the `ci` specifies the color identity to look for. This returns 241 cards, which can be reasonably looked through. If a card matching your criteria doesn't show up in those search results, it doesn't exist.

There are a couple of common ways that cards could allow allow you to search for sorceries that suggest ways to refine that search. Some cards could allow you to search specifically for sorcery cards. A simple way to search for that would be to just add a search for the word "sorcery": [`o:"search your library" ci:g o:sorcery`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22search%20your%20library%22%20ci%3Ag%20o%3Asorcery). This search returns two cards, both of which are false positives.

Other cards might allow you to search for any card. The phrasing for this is "Search your library for a card", so the following search would find cards like that: [`o:"search your library for a card" ci:g`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22search%20your%20library%20for%20a%20card%22%20ci%3Ag). This finds 14 cards; most find cards with a specific name, or names that match another name, but three cards match requested criteria: [Planar Portal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPlanar%20Portal%5d), [Ring of Three Wishes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRing%20of%20Three%20Wishes%5d), and [Tamiyo's Journal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTamiyo%27s%5d%2b%5bJournal%5d).

Finally, some cards allow you to search for nonland cards, but the search for that ([`o:"search your library" ci:g o:nonland`](https://scryfall.com/search?q=o%3A%22search%20your%20library%22%20ci%3Ag%20o%3Anonland)) finds no results.

---

Some specific Sorcery cards can be found by other search effects. The [few green and colorless tribal sorceries](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Asorcery%20t%3Atribal%20ci%3Ag) can be found by any effect that instructs you to search for cards with that specific creature subtype (such as [Wirewood Herald](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWirewood%20Herald%5d)). And the [creature cards with with Adventure instants and sorceries](https://scryfall.com/search?q=t%3Aadventure) can be found by any effect that instructs you to search for a creature, which are plentiful in green.

Comment: I'll include Tamiyo's journal, because it's the cheapest one... (I'm such a poor guy)

Answer (score 0):

In general, green is not a color that cares about instants and sorceries.  Green specializes in tutoring for lands and creatures - to tutor for sorceries you need either blue or black (which can tutor for anything).  Red might also have some, as it's second in caring about instants and sorceries, but I'm not sure.

There are a few specific spells that green *can* tutor for - the Tribal spells from Lorwyn and Morningtide, which can be tutored for by using the tutor of that respective creature type.  But that only works for that particular subset of spells - if you need to search for any other spell you're out of luck.

In general, your best bet is to look for the effect you need stapled to a creature.

Comment: The sorcery I want is a sorcery that makes me search for a LOT of lands so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

From some of the comments you've made in this question, it seems like you're building a [Molimo, Maro-Sorcerer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMolimo%2c%20Maro-Sorcerer%5d) deck and you're planning on using [Boundless Realms](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBoundless%20Realms%5d) as your win condition.  Others have already said there's a distinct lack of either Sorcery tutors or generic tutors in mono-green, so you're kind of limited there.

However, there are a number of cards that achieve similar results to Boundless Realms, including several that are near-functional reprints or achieve the same goal as dumping lands onto the battlefield for the purposes of your Commander.

(Side Note: If you aren't familiar with it, I would strongly suggest checking EDHREC when building Commanders, as it maintains a large database of Commander decks, including lists of the most popular cards for specific Commanders.)

[EDHREC](https://edhrec.com/commanders/molimo-maro-sorcerer) has a good list of cards that are extremely popular in Molimo, and your Boundless Realms is certainly one of them, but there are a number of other options in there that you are going to want to at least consider.

- [Ranger's Path](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRanger%27s%5d%2b%5bPath%5d) and [Explosive Vegetation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExplosive%20Vegetation%5d) give you two additional lands and come out on Turn 4, allowing you to power out a Turn 5 Molimo instead of a Turn 7.
- [mtg Traverse the Outlands] is at least a functional copy of Boudless Realms if you have Molimo on the battlefield and comes in at 2 mana cheaper.
- [Kalonian Twingrove](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKalonian%20Twingrove%5d), [Ulvenwald Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bUlvenwald%20Hydra%5d), and [Dungrove Elder](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDungrove%20Elder%5d) are all alternate win conditions if your commander gets hit with a [Pacifism](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPacifism%5d) or something similar.
- [Blanchwood Armor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBlanchwood%20Armor%5d) and [Primal Bellow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPrimal%20Bellow%5d) achieve effectively the same thing as Boundless Realms if you're running only basics, and Primal Bellow even has the benefit of being a combat trick, allowing you to sneak in an extra boost on your Commander after blockers are declared to pull a win out of no where.

There are plenty of other cards on that page that synchronize with what you're trying to accomplish with your commander (dump as many lands/forests onto the battlefield as physically possible).  I would recommend that you go through the rest of page yourself and take a look to see what you like.

Comment: My commander is Budoka Gardener and the sorcery is animist’s awakening

Comment: @Spyro999 you should know that, according to the official rules of EDH, Budoka isn't a legal commander.  If you're playing kitchen table magic you should check with your playgroup, and if you intent to go to an actual tournament they probably won't let you play it.  The problem is that Budoka Gardner doesn't enter the Battlefield as a Legendary Creature.  While you can flip it to become one, it isn't one when it enters the battlefield, and that is what makes a creature a legal commander.

Comment: I know it but my friends told me that’s it’s fine for our playgroup... we are only playing casual

Comment: @Spyro999 you should also know that Animist's Awakening isn't going to double your lands.  That's why I thought you were playing Boundless Realms, because Boundless Realms would actually double your land count.  Assuming you have no mana ramp and a 40% land ratio, Animist's Awakening will only hit 40% of the number of lands you have in play, on average, so you're not going to be able to double your land count by just dumping mana into an Animist's Awakening.

Comment: With ramps and the ratio I have calculated it does more or less double the lands